# Branchless method to convert false/true to -1/+1?

Tags: python, data-conversion

What is a branchless way to do the following mapping?

```
true -> +1
false -> -1
```

An easy way would be `if b then 1 else -1` but I'm looking for a method to avoid the branch, i.e. if.

If it is relevant, I'm using Python.

Comment: "but I'm looking for a method to avoid the branch"—why?

Comment: `{True: 1}.get(foo, -1)`

Comment: @deceze, clever answer! But awful readability (which I know you know). OP, clarity is one of the most important things in programming. In Python it's especially important (it's part of being "Pythonic"). If you're going to do something unexpected or hard to read you should have a good reason for it.

Comment: Python’s ternary `1 if foo else -1` is not a “branching if” per se, it’s an expression. To what extent does that violate your arbitrary restriction…?

Comment: @deceze It is branching in the sense that it is compiled to bytecode which does a conditional jump.

Comment: `b -= (b - 1) * -1`

Comment: @kaya3 Sure, but most solutions will do that somewhere. So it’s really important to clarify what we’re really trying to work around here.

Comment: Including false in the dictionary and just doing a normal dictionary lookup would avoid that but I still dont understand why you'd do this

Comment: I agree with some of the other commenters, this is bizarre. Can you clarify things?

Comment: @Chris I'm not really sure why there needs to be reason for the question. Intellectual curiosity? Performance? I mentioned Python, but it can just as well be assembly language, in which case there are obvious reasons to avoid branching (i.e. branch misprediction).

Comment: @deceze An `if` generates a condition jump in the processor opcode. Most solutions _do_ do that, which is why I'm asking this question! Are there ways to avoid a branch?

Comment: @puritii, _of course_ the reason is important. Intellectual curiosity and performance lead to different answers, e.g. alternative solutions may be interesting but perform _worse_. And futzing around with saving single opcodes in a language like Python is questionable at best. "I mentioned Python, but it can just as well be assembly language"—then your question is too broad. It's _very_ unusual for a valid question to have multiple language tags here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can exploit the fact that in Python, the type `bool` is numeric:

```py
>>> True == 1
True
>>> False == 0
True
```

So the expression `2 * b - 1` gives the desired results:

```py
>>> def without_branching(b):
...     return 2 * b - 1
... 
>>> without_branching(True)
1
>>> without_branching(False)
-1
```

However, it's arguable whether even this is really "branchless". It will be compiled to Python bytecode with no conditional jumps, but the bytecode interpreter will certainly do some conditional jumps in order to execute it: at the very least, it has to check which opcodes to execute, what types the operands of `*` and `-` have, and so on.

Comment: Good answer, but again, I'll caution OP to favour readability. I'd like to know why `if b then 1 else -1` is unacceptable since it's much clearer.

Comment: On your last sentence: there shouldn't be any branching internally on True vs. False: `True` and `False` really _do_ store the values `1` and `0` internally, so the rest is just arithmetic. More generally, there will of course be lots of branches as the interpreter interprets the bytecode, but not as a result of the `True` / `False` distinction.

Comment: @MarkDickinson I meant there is surely branching to check what the opcode is, and/or what the types of the operands are, and so on. But I'll edit to clarify that, thank you.

Comment: @kaya3: And of course I'm wrong, since the integer multiplication code almost certainly special-cases zero ... Specifically, I think `MEDIUM_VALUE` is branchy in this line: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/aef7dc89879d099dc704bd8037b8a7686fb72838/Objects/longobject.c#L3660

Answer (score 6):

Here's a comparison of the solutions posted in comments and answers so far.

We can use the [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) module to see the generated bytecode in each case; this confirms that there are no conditional jump instructions (in the Python code itself, at least), and also tells us something about the expected performance, since the number of opcodes executed has a direct impact on that (though they are not perfectly correlated). The number of function calls is also relevant for performance, since these have a particularly high overhead.

#### @Glannis Clipper and @kaya3: `(-1, 1)[b]` (3 opcodes)

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               2 ((-1, 1))
              3 LOAD_NAME                0 (b)
              6 BINARY_SUBSCR
```

#### @HeapOverflow: `-(-1)**b` (4 opcodes)

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (-1)
              2 LOAD_NAME                0 (b)
              4 BINARY_POWER
              6 UNARY_NEGATIVE
```

#### @HeapOverflow: `b - (not b)` (4 opcodes)

```
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (b)
              2 LOAD_NAME                0 (b)
              4 UNARY_NOT
              6 BINARY_SUBTRACT
```

#### @kaya3: `2 * b - 1` (5 opcodes)

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (2)
              3 LOAD_NAME                0 (b)
              6 BINARY_MULTIPLY
              7 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             10 BINARY_SUBTRACT
```

#### @HeapOverflow: `~b ^ -b` (5 opcodes)

```
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (b)
              2 UNARY_INVERT
              4 LOAD_NAME                0 (b)
              6 UNARY_NEGATIVE
              8 BINARY_XOR
```

#### @Mark Meyer: `b - (b - 1) * -1` (7 opcodes)

```
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (b)
              3 LOAD_NAME                0 (b)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              9 BINARY_SUBTRACT
             10 LOAD_CONST               1 (-1)
             13 BINARY_MULTIPLY
             14 BINARY_SUBTRACT
```

#### @Sayse: `{True: 1, False: -1}[b]` (7 opcodes)

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (True)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (False)
              9 LOAD_CONST               3 (-1)
             12 BUILD_MAP                2
             15 LOAD_NAME                0 (b)
             18 BINARY_SUBSCR
```

#### @deceze: `{True: 1}.get(b, -1)` (7 opcodes, 1 function call)

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (True)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              6 BUILD_MAP                1
              9 LOAD_ATTR                0 (get)
             12 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
             15 LOAD_CONST               2 (-1)
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            2 (2 positional, 0 keyword pair)
```

#### @Glannis Clipper: `[-1, 1][int(b)]` (7 opcodes, 1 function call)

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (-1)
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              6 BUILD_LIST               2
              9 LOAD_NAME                0 (int)
             12 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
             15 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             18 BINARY_SUBSCR
```

#### @divyang4481: `2 * int(b) - 1` (7 opcodes, 1 function call)

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (2)
              3 LOAD_NAME                0 (int)
              6 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             12 BINARY_MULTIPLY
             13 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             16 BINARY_SUBTRACT
```

Comment: @HeapOverflow I removed the RETURN_VALUE opcodes from your edits for consistency - they are an artifact of `dis` and not relevant for the comparison.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe we can use a list in a way like this:

```
[None, True, False][1]
# output True

[None, True, False][-1]
# output False
```

UPDATE: And the opposite way as mentioned in comments:

```
[-1, 1][int(False)]
# output -1

[-1, 1][int(True)]
# output 1
```

UPDATE: Or even simpler with the use of a tuple and without the need of int() conversion (as mentioned in comments too):

```
(-1, 1)[False]
# output -1

(-1, 1)[True]
# output 1
```