# What is the best way to make branchless counters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, branchless

I am working on a counter in Python3 for devices in the field. It tries to contact the device and returns the total number that are online and offline.

```
def count_online(mac_list):
    online = 0
    offline = 0

    for mac in mac_list:

        is_online = poll_device(mac) # ask the device if it is online, return bool

        if is_online:
            online += 1
        else:
            offline += 1

    return online, offline
```

I have seen "[Branchless method to convert false/true to -1/+1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59912130/branchless-method-to-convert-false-true-to-1-1)" as well as "[Why "If" is Sloowww](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bVJ-mWWL7cE)", however I need a count of both the online *and* offline devices. I also appreciate that in Python, trying to go branchless is arguably a bit pointless as it's not a low level language like C. On the other hand, the [Hopper Necklace](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9eyFDBPk4Yw) reminds us not to waste our microseconds, so is there a more efficient way to write this? Would a branchless approach decrease run time?

Comment: How do you get `online`?

Comment: `online += poll_device(mac)` where the `return` is either `True` or `False`. Then just do what @snakecharmerb recommended.

Comment: How about `online += 1 if poll_device(mac) else offline += 1` @JamesGeddes?

Comment: @Alok wont work  - cant sideeffect offline in that way

Comment: What you have written is already the clearest and simplest way to write this.

Comment: Can you add some information about what specific, objective criteria you consider when you mean "better"?

Comment: @TylerH I have updated the question to define "better". I am looking for an implementation that runs faster, perhaps using a branchless approach. Can you reopen the question, please?

Comment: This sounds like premature optimization. `poll_device()` involves a network call, right? If yes, I would wager almost all of your time will be spent on that call and whatever counting method you use will be miniscule by comparison.  It's probably better to profile and refactor your code only if you have real performance issues.

Comment: This may be more appropriate for CodeReview instead of Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add up the Trues and subtract them from the length - this will give you a branchless code:

```
def poll_device(_):
    poll_device.state = not poll_device.state
    return poll_device.state

poll_device.state = False

def count_online(mac_list):
    online = 0
    offline = 0
    for mac in mac_list:
        online += poll_device(mac) # ask the device if it is online, return bool

    return online, len(mac_list)-online

on,off = count_online(range(10))

print(on,off)

import dis

dis.dis(count_online)
```

Output:

```
5 5

# disassembly
  9           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              2 STORE_FAST               1 (online)

 10           4 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              6 STORE_FAST               2 (offline)

 11           8 SETUP_LOOP              24 (to 34)
             10 LOAD_FAST                0 (mac_list)
             12 GET_ITER
        >>   14 FOR_ITER                16 (to 32)
             16 STORE_FAST               3 (mac)

 12          18 LOAD_FAST                1 (online)
             20 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (poll_device)
             22 LOAD_FAST                3 (mac)
             24 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             26 INPLACE_ADD
             28 STORE_FAST               1 (online)
             30 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           14
        >>   32 POP_BLOCK

 14     >>   34 LOAD_FAST                1 (online)
             36 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (len)
             38 LOAD_FAST                0 (mac_list)
             40 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             42 LOAD_FAST                1 (online)
             44 BINARY_SUBTRACT
             46 BUILD_TUPLE              2
             48 RETURN_VALUE
```

Versus your codes disassembly:

```
 21           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              2 STORE_FAST               1 (online)

 22           4 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              6 STORE_FAST               2 (offline)

 24           8 SETUP_LOOP              42 (to 52)
             10 LOAD_FAST                0 (mac_list)
             12 GET_ITER
        >>   14 FOR_ITER                34 (to 50)
             16 STORE_FAST               3 (mac)

 26          18 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (poll_device)
             20 LOAD_FAST                3 (mac)
             22 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             24 STORE_FAST               4 (is_online)

 28          26 LOAD_FAST                4 (is_online)
             28 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       40

 29          30 LOAD_FAST                1 (online)
             32 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             34 INPLACE_ADD
             36 STORE_FAST               1 (online)
             38 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           14

 31     >>   40 LOAD_FAST                2 (offline)
             42 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             44 INPLACE_ADD
             46 STORE_FAST               2 (offline)
             48 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           14
        >>   50 POP_BLOCK

 33     >>   52 LOAD_FAST                1 (online)
             54 LOAD_FAST                2 (offline)
             56 BUILD_TUPLE              2
             58 RETURN_VALUE
```

---

But I am not quite sure that kind of "optimization" beforehand is wise to to - I would simply go for the `if ... else ...` approach until this code part is a bottleneck (measuring it)... the call towards `poll_device(mac)` is 100-1000 times slower then this branchless construct and *that* is eating your performance.

Comment: "But I am not quite sure that kind of "optimization" beforehand is wise to do ... until this code part is a bottleneck (measuring it)." This is truth here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that `isinstance(True, int)` and use pure mathematical operations with one go on your input iterator (which doesn't have to be a list):

```py
def count_online(mac_list):
    online_cnt = sum(poll_device(mac) for mac in mac_list)
    offline_cnt = len(mac_list) - online_cnt

    return online_cnt, offline_cnt
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def count_online(mac_list):
    online = sum(map(poll_device, mac_list))
    return online, len(mac_list) - online
```